# How to add Spinner-Gif before ng-include is fully loaded

Tags: angularjs, ajax, spinner

I have a div-layer which dynamically loads html-partials from the server. The template variable is changed when a link in the navigation is clicked.

```
<div id="ajaxwrapper" ng-include="template">
</div>
```

This works fine. But the templates need a short time to load and during that time the user doesn't get any kind of response. Thats why I want to display a spinner until the template is load. Sadly I don't know how.

My links look something like this:

```
<a ng-click="navi($event)" href="www.someurl.de">Text</a>
```

The navi-function looks like this:

```
 $scope.navi = function (elem) {
    elem.preventDefault();
    var urlstring = "";
    if (typeof elem.target.href !== 'undefined') {
        urlstring = elem.target.href;
        $location.path(elem.target.pathname).search({ knt: $scope.aktuellesVertragskonto.nr });;
    } else {
        urlstring = elem.target.baseURI
        $location.path("/");
    }
    $scope.template = $location.absUrl();
};
```

I need some pointers on how to implement a spinner. Thank you :)

The spinner-template would look like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="loader">
<div class="text-center">
    <img src="~/images/spinner/ajax-loader.gif" /><br />
    Loading
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-include` directive includes an `onload` expression ([reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)), so you can do something like this:

```
<div id="ajaxwrapper" 
     ng-show="loaded"
     ng-include="template" onload="loaded = true">
</div>

<div class="text-center"
     ng-hide="loaded">
    <img src="~/images/spinner/ajax-loader.gif" /><br />
    Loading
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, such a simple and elegant solution, thank you. Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another way as well, as ng-include override inside div html so you can show loader till template loads.

You can put loader inside the div as below.

```
<div id="ajaxwrapper" ng-include="template">
  // Show loader image or css
</div>
```